# How do I install ubuntu server from a usb stick?

Tags: installation

How do I install ubuntu server system from a usb stick?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) or [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)? The steps are identical for Ubuntu Server. Just replace the desktop image with the server image

Comment: **Add more detail (to question).** Do you need help creating the USB image, or on how to actually install? What server hardware spec.? *What have you tried? What do you know about Linux / Ubuntu?*

Answer (score -1):

First you need to download the Server ISO that you require.  Go [Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server) to get either the **32bit or 64bit 12.04 LTS** or the **64bit 13.04** version.  Once you get that done, I recommend that you download [Yumi](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) to create you bootable USB stick.  Once created, make sure that you switch you BIOS to boot fro the USB stick, and just follow the steps.

**Note:** With Yumi you can also add other distros to either install or try, as well as other utilities.

[image]